# Excel VBA to define specific ranges within large data sets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that is constantly being updated, and to keep track of the updates I want to insert a formula into Column AL which draws a number from the instructions page, and I want that formula to be converted to a value so it doesn't keep changing (Every time the sheet is updated this number changes).

Problem is, I don't know how to define my range - my code works and it pastes the data, inserts the formula and then converts it to a value only. But it does this for the entire column because its defined at AL1. I want to define it for the previous last used row, and then once the new data is pasted, I want it to stop at the last used row of the new data. I'm not too sure if my explanation makes any sense so let me know if you have any questions or ideas how I can do this! Thanks :)

```
With ThisWorkbook
  With .Sheets("ABC")
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    lrFormula = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Set Period = .Range("AL1:AL" & lrPPV)
    Period.Formula = "=Instructions!$E$33"
    Period.Value = Period.Value
  End With
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Dim Lastrow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook

        With .Sheets("ABC")

            Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Lastrow before paste
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
            lrFormula = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Set Period = .Range("AL" & Lastrow & ":AL" & lrPPV)
            Period.Formula = "=Instructions!$E$33"
            Period.Value = Period.Value

        End With

    End With
```

Comment: @Leena i have correct the answer, try it now and provide a feedback.

Comment: Now there is an application or object define error in the same line

Comment: Check the value of lrPPV.

Comment: I did, I just ran the code again and now there's another syntax error in the same line

Comment: The Period is declair as range?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185368/discussion-between-error-1004-and-leena).